# TypeError : 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: sklearn-pandas

The error i have is this:
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

```
      pd.DataFrame({'Pokemon_name':test.Pokemon_name,'CP':new_pred_class}).set_index['Pokemon_name'].to_csv['new_pred_cp.csv']
```

Im trying to write the results to a new csv file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.to_csv` is a function/method, and you can't use `[]` after it, it must be `()`.

So the code should be:

```
....['Pokemon_name'].to_csv("new_pred_cp.csv")
```